# RabbitMQ HA with Durable features

Tags: rabbitmq

### Background

I have a RabbitMQ cluster that running for more than a year without any problems. Lastly, I found that sometimes, the CPU of the machine is touching the 100% CPU. I'm investigating ways to increase the throughput of the cluster to serve more customers.

The cluster architecture is that we have HA enabled (exactly 1 replica), and durable messages (for all the queues). As I understand it, the `durable` feature is the most expensive one in terms of performance. So, I trying to understand if it is needed for me.

### Question

According to my experience, the cluster was running for more than a year without problems. So I assume that the chance for a problem is very low. Even after this, I want to create another layer of protection, just in case...

If I have two servers that holding the same data, but not storing it into the disk (durable OFF), is not safe enough for 99.99% of the cases? Those two servers are in different regions so the chance that both of them will go down is very low. Wondering if saving it to the disk can be helpful, or just a waste?

There is a thumb rule about the performance improvements of disabling the durable feature? In percents.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The influence of durable on performance

For reliable delivery, rabbitmq use the publish confirmation mechanism. Everytime the publisher publish a message to rabbitmq server, the server will respond with `basic.ack` rpc to ack the message. For routable messages, the basic.ack is sent when a message has been accepted by all the queues. For persistent messages routed to durable queues, this means persisting to disk. For mirrored queues, this means that all mirrors have accepted the message. So as you mentioned, the IO may become bottlenect of performance.

#### Is it overhead both durable and mirrored

It depends on your consideration between performance and HA. Imagine if you declare non-durable mirrored queue, and the master and slave are down, your messages will get lost. So whether overhead depends on how important message safty is.

#### Is the performance bottleneck mainly caused by durable?

As we discussed, if you declare non-durable queue, the throught maybe increase. But this may not be the main cause of low performance. You have said the cpu usage sometimes is 100%, which means very little I/O waitting. The high load maybe due to many connections and high throughput. In order to determine how to increase throughput, you can use [benchmark](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test) tool to find the bottleneck.

pages maybe useful:

1. https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2016-01-25-identify-and-protect-against-high-cpu-and-memory-usage.html
2. https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2018-01-08-part2-rabbitmq-best-practice-for-high-performance.html